# How do I get a specific value from a key in a dictionary with multiple values per key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in this format:

`my_dict = {"key1":["value1", "value2", "value3"]}`

Is there an easy way to get key1's third value?
I guess I could get the whole list of values and then split it up, but there must be a better way

Comment: You want to access always the third value or you want to access the last one? Small difference but important one

Comment: @LorenzoZane the third one

Comment: And what should happen if the list does have three values?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple look up in the following ways -

```
my_dict['key1'][2]

#Output = 'value3'
```

OR (using dict.get)

```
my_dict.get('key1')[2]

#Output = 'value3'
```

OR (if you want 3rd element without specifying the key)

```
list(my_dict.values())[0][2]

#Output = 'value3'
```

OR (if you want last element without specifying the key)

```
list(my_dict.values())[0][-1]

#Output = 'value3'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict['key1'][2]
```

You access the list in. the value like any other list

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `get` i.e. `my_dict.get('key1')[2]`

If you use `my_dict['key1'][2]` , you will get a `KeyError` if `key1` is not present in `my_dict`

Example -

```
>>> d = {1:3,4:6}
>>> d.get(7) # No Error
>>> d[7] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 7
```